# Bad return type in lambda expression: Model1 cannot be converted to Model2

Tags: java, lambda

Why does the exception 'ad return type in lambda expression: AuthenticatedUser cannot be converted to User' happen? I just want to return this AuthenticatedUser if Optional is null.

```
  User user = new User("d","d","d");
        return s -> {
            List<User> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(TestData.BASIC_USER_ENTITY, TestData.ADMIN_USER_ENTITY));
            return new AuthenticatedUser(
                    list.stream()
                            .filter(u -> u.getUsername().equals(s))
                            .findAny()
                            .orElseGet(() -> new AuthenticatedUser(new User()))); // Bad return type in lambda expression: AuthenticatedUser cannot be converted to User
        };
```

Comment: I would assume it's because `AuthenticatedUser` doesn't extend `User`. It probably should.

Comment: No it does not, it takes User in Constructor.

Comment: Change `.orElseGet(() -> new AuthenticatedUser(new User()))` to `.orElseGet(() -> new User())` (or `.orElseGet(User::new)`). The return type of the `orElseGet(...)`-lambda must match (i.e. assignable to) the generic type of the `Optional` (which is `User`, not `AuthenticatedUser`).

Answer (score 2):

If we inspect the operations on the stream closely, we can make the following observations:

```
list.stream()  // produces a Stream<User>
    .filter(u -> u.getUsername().equals(s)) // still a Stream<User>
    .findAny() // produces an Optional<User>
    .orElseGet(() -> new AuthenticatedUser(new User())
```

The return-type of the lambda that is passed along to `orElseGet(...)` must be assignment-compatible of the generic type of the `Optional`. In our case, the generic type of the `Optional` is `User`. Thus, we can rewrite the code to:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(u -> u.getUsername().equals(s))
    .findAny()
    .orElseGet(User::new)
```